# Dynamic web scraping in android phones without pc

Tags: android, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup, headless-browser

Is there a headless browser support for android like headless chrome but it needs adb server running which requires a pc. I want to make an app which embeds headless browser and can do scrolling events and scrape dynamic data from websites in the app itself.

Jsoup does the html parsing but it doesnot parse the dynamic data so i need headless browser or something to mimic scrolling events in the app itself.

Or is there anything better then jsoup?

I have gone through alot of old posts in stackoverflow, didnt seem to find anything similar to my needs. Hope there are solutions now..

Comment: did you find any solution? I am facing a similar issue :(

Comment: Yes i kind of got a work around.. but its static not dynamic...

Comment: can you post workable code as a answer, It will can be helpful for everyone else including myself?